# What is the better way to write the update query?

Tags: sql, database

The following two queries achieve what I want to do with my tables:

```
Update person_role_memberships, events
set person_role_id = 2
where person_role_id = 32 and event_name = events.name and events.date_2 = curdate() - 1
 ;
```

-

```
 update person_role_memberships set person_role_id = 2
where person_role_id = 32 and event_name in 
    (select name from events where date_2 = curdate() -1
    );
```

I want to know which is the better way of doing that in terms of optimality, safety (corner cases or side-effects) or best practices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first version is clearly not standard SQL, since multiple tables before the `SET` are not allowed.

```
Update person_role_memberships, events SET
```

Also "optimality" depends on the actual product and version you intend to use.
But as long as there is no other reason I would go with standard SQL as far as possible.

as a minor idea for improvement (i.e. you should test it) you may substitute the `IN` part with `EXISTS`

```
... and exists(select 1 from events where event_name = event.name and date_2 = curdate() -1)
```

Comment: I want to run the update query for every record returned by `select name from events where date_2 = curdate() -1` - would `exists` do that? I though exists for just testing whether anything was returned or not.

Comment: You thought right but the test for existence includes `person_role_memberships.event_name = event.name`. It is the same as your `IN` selection.

Comment: The `EXISTS` will return true if the right hand side returns a row. The contents of the row is not important. Therefore `1` will just do the job.